# Can someone help why app logo is not showing up in Google oath consent screen?

Tags: google-oauth

I have configured the Google oath 2.0 for by web app for Internal Use (so the verification is not required). Everything is working fine, except App Logo is not showing up in User Consent Screen?

I have tried all options as per documentation. Still logo doesn't shows up. However, it authenticates perfectly.